# Unable to call OData service for "http://abc-xyz.com:8082/discovery.svc" URL and service query "/TokenServiceCapabilities"

Tags: dxa, web8, dxa-java, dxa-2.0

In our DXA application, we are trying to check connectivity of our webapp to a new PROD CMS Environment. However, I keep getting the following error, trying to run the app, and not sure why it cannot access the service even though it is the correct one. Please suggest what could be wrong. DXA is new to us and we are really not sure where to start looking for this issue.

> Caused by: **org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException**: Failed to instantiate [com.sdl.dxa.tridion.modelservice.ModelServiceConfiguration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is **com.sdl.odata.client.api.exception.ODataClientRuntimeException**: Unable to call OData service for "http://abc-xyz.com:8082/discovery.svc" URL and service query "/TokenServiceCapabilities"

Comment: Have you verified that the service is running at that endpoint?

Comment: Yes it is, actually since its PROD we needed to add host entry which was missing. Its now resolved.

Comment: In that case, please copy your comment to an answer and accept it so the question becomes "closed".

Answer (score 1):

Actually since its PROD we needed to add host entry which was missing. Its now resolved.